# How to prove $AB = AC$ in $\triangle ABC, E\in AB, F\in AC, D$ is midpoint $BC, DE \cap BF=G, DF\cap CE=H, AE=AF, EG=FH.$

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC, E\in AB, F\in AC, D$ is midpoint $BC, DE \cap BF=G, DF\cap CE=H, AE=AF, EG=FH.$
How to prove $AB = AC$? 
 I knew taht: if $BE > CF$，then $DE < DF$.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a drawing?

Comment: I've attached the drawing.

Comment: Will try to find a more elegant solution...:)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $AE=AF=u$ and that $A$ lies in the origin, we have $D=\frac{B+C}{2}, E=\frac{u}{c}B$ and $F=\frac{u}{b}C$. By using barycentric coordinates we have:

$$ G=\frac{(bu+cu-2u^2)B+(cu-u^2)C}{bc+cu-2u^2},$$
$$ H=\frac{(bu-u^2)B+(bc+cu-2u^2)C}{bu+cu-2u^2},$$
hence:
$$ G-E = \frac{u(c-u)(c-2u)}{c(bc+cu-2u^2)}B+\frac{u(c-u)}{bc+cu-2u^2}C$$
$$ H-F = \frac{u(b-u)(b-2u)}{b(bc+bu-2u^2)}C+\frac{u(b-u)}{bc+bu-2u^2}B.$$

Now it is just incredibly tedious to check that $\|G-E\|^2 = \|H-F\|^2$ implies $b=c$.